# AWS CodeBuild buildspec.yml get all files and subfolders recursively

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to use AWS CodeBuild to get all files and subfolders inside a nested `public` folder and deploy to an S3 bucket using CodePipeline. I was able to hook them all together but struggling to configure the `buildspec.yml` file to get the output I want.

My folder structure:

```
<path>/public/

├── 404.html
├── css
│   ├── ...
├── fonts
│   ├── bootstrap
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── icomoon
│   │   ├── icomoon
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   └── simple-line-icons
│       ├── ...
├── images
│   ├── ...
├── index.html
├── index.xml
├── js
│   ├── ...
└── tags
    └── index.xml
```

I need to put everything (including the subfolders) inside the `public` folder into the root of an S3 bucket.

So far I've tried following the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-name-storage), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax) and [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/codebuild/latest/userguide/codebuild-user.pdf). I've tried using:

- `**/*` to get everything recursively inside the folder `public` but the S3 bucket will have the path to the folder so the `index.html` is not in the root.
- `discard-paths: yes` to remove the path to the `public` folder but inside the S3 bucket, all files are there in the root, no sub-folder structure is kept.
- `base-directory`: as described [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=247585).
- `artifacts:
  secondary-artifacts:
  artifact1:
    files:
      - directory/file
  artifact2:
    files:
      - directory/file2` to keep the folder structure but my build failed.
- Different combinations of all the syntaxes above but my build just failed.

Comment: you need `files` straight after `artifacts` too, regardless of secondary artifacts, otherwise it will always fail

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've figured out a way to work around it. I don't think it's the best way but it works. I hope you can find this solution useful `buildspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - mkdir build-output
      - cp -R <path>/public/ build-output
  post_build:
    commands:
      - mv build-output/**/* ./
      - mv build-output/* ./
      - rm -R build-output *.yml LICENSE README* .git*
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

In words:

- I copy everything inside the nested `<path>/public` folder out to a folder called `./build-output`.
- Then in `post_build` I move everything out of folder `build-output`.
- Delete files pulled from my GitHub's repo which aren't needed to host the static website in the `S3 bucket`
- Then I get the result I want: all files inside `public` in the root of the `S3 bucket` with the right folder tree.

> Update:

- You can also use my `buildspec.yml` example file [here](https://github.com/nditech/tech-staticsite-cicd/blob/master/buildspec.yml). Since the example is out of the scope of this question, I don't paste the code here.
- I explain in details [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-build-pipeline-automate-deployment-github-aws-codebuild-nguyen/).

Comment: A comment about symlinks: I've tried to use this approach, but my files had symlinks and codebuild lose them all when zipping the files. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245780
In my solution, I had to create a tarball myself, unfortunately.

Comment: this answer seems promising, but when I check my S3, I still received all files instead of specific build directory. Do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 55):

**TL;DR** You probably **don't** need to use "*discard-paths: yes*". So, drop "*discard-paths: yes*" and instead use "*base-directory*" with "***/**" for glob pattern. Read on for more reasoning why.

So yeah, as it usually happens, the culprit was pretty trivial. In my case the directory structure looked like this:

```
dist/
|-- favicon.ico
|-- index.html
|-- js
|   `-- app.js
`-- revision.txt
```

So in order for the artifact to contain everything from the "*dist*" directory whilst preserving the nested directories structure, the buildspec had to look like this:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'dist'
```

Essentially "*base-directory*" parameter behaves as unix's "cd" command, so at first CodeBuild jumps to that directory and only after that resolves the glob pattern, in this case - ***/**. If you also happen to use "*discard-paths*" then what happens is that, presumably, CodeBuild will change current directory to "*dist*", resolve the files structure correctly **but** then remove all path prefixes from the resolved paths, thus the result will be a plain directory structure with no nesting.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Removing 'discard-paths' made it work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was running into a similar issue and after many permutations below syntax worked for me.

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - './**/*'
  base-directory: public
  name: websitename
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
    /
    buildspec.yml
    /public
        index.html
        /js
        /img
        appspec.yml
    /src
```

in buildspec.yml

```
    artifacts:
    files:
      - 'public/*'
    discard-paths: yes
```

Comment: as @Butiri Dan, mentioned, adding `discard-paths: yes` helped me with corretto11. Because the runtime was expecting the jar file in the root of zip file according to the logs.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are facing this issue while using CodeBuid in CodePipline and have tried the correct configuration for buildspec.yml file, the culprit for me was on the deploy stage, where I had set as Input Artifact the Source artifact instead of the Build artifact.

Answer (score 1):

For me a very simple construct like this was enough:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - 'dist/**/*'
```